# in powershell i need to split and extract Worldwide Web Publishing Service from string " The resouce worldwide publishing service is not available

Tags: powershell

in powershell i need to split and extract 
World Wide Web Publishing Service 
from string " The resource worldwide publishing service is not available"

I have tried Replace method but it doesn't work

```
$message="The Resource World Wide Publishing Service is not available"
$newmessage=($message.Replace("The Resource is not available","")).ToString()
Write-Host $newmessage
```

but the output $newmessage is still The Resource is not available

Comment: What did you try so far? Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens here is that the search part doesn't match the target string. The [`String.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.7#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_) expects a literal match.

In the sample, there is no such string as `The Resource is not available`. Yes, the words are there, but `World Wide Publishing Service` is between those, so it's not a match.

As a solution, do multiple replace operations or use a regex. The simple replace is like so,

```
$message.Replace("The Resource ","").Replace(" is not available", "")
World Wide Publishing Service
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@vonPryz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51727233/6579295), you can also use aforementioned RegEx:

```
$message='The Resource World Wide Publishing Service is not available'
$match = [Regex]::Match($message, 'The Resource (.*) is not available')
if ($match.Success) {
    Write-Host $match.Groups[1].Value
} else {
    Write-Host 'Invalid input'
}
```